# How to intercept accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application, with two models: SalesTransactions and PurchaseOrders.

In the PurchaseOrders model, new entries are registered using 'purchase_order_number' as the key field.  I use the create method of the model to search if that 'purchase_order_number' has been previously registered, and if so, reuse that record and use its id in the SalesTransaction record.  If that name wasn't already registered, I go ahead and perform the create, and then use the new PurchaseOrder record id in the SalesTransaction (the foreign_id linking to the associated PO).

Note that I don't have the existing PurchaseOrder record id until I've done a look-up in the create method (so this is not a question of 'how do I update a record using 'accepts_nested_attributes_for'?', I can do that once I have the id).

In some situations, my application records a new SalesTransaction, and creates a new PurchaseOrder at the same time. It uses accepts_nested_attributes_for to create the PurchaseOrder record.

The problem appears to be that when using 'accepts_nested_attributes_for', create is not called and so my model does not have the opportunity to intercept the create, and look-up if the 'purchase_order_number' has already been registered and handle that case.

I'd appreciate suggestions as to how to intercept 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' creations to allow some pre-processing (i.e. look up if the PurchaseOrder record with that number already exists, and if so, use it).

Not all Sales have a PurchaseOrder, so the PurchaseOrder record is optional within a SalesTransaction.

(I've seen a kludge involving :reject_if, but that does not allow me to add the existing record id as the foreign_id within the parent record.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've left this question out there for a while, and offered a bounty, but I've not got the answer I'm looking for (though I certainly appreciate folk trying to help).

I'm concluding that I wasn't missing some trick and, at the time of writing, there isn't a neat solution, only work-arounds.

As such, I'm going to rewrite my App to avoid using accept_nested_attributes_for, and post the  SalesTransaction and the PurchaseOrder records separately, so the create code can be applied in both cases.

A shame, as accept_nested... is pretty cool otherwise, but it's not complete enough in this case.

I still love Rails ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `validate` and `save` callbacks to do what you need.

Assuming the setup:

```
class SalesTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchase_order, :foreign_key => "po_purchase_order_no", 
    :primary_key => "purchase_order_no"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchase_order
end

class PurchaseOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales_transactions, :foreign_key => "po_purchase_order_no", 
    :primary_key => "purchase_order_no"

  before_validation :check_for_exisitng_po # maybe only on create?

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sales_transactions

  private

  def check_for_exisitng_po
    existing_po = PurchaseOrder.find_by_purchase_order_no(self.purchase_order_no)

    if existing_po
      self.id = existing_po.id
      self.reload # don't like this, also will overwrite incoming attrs
      @new_record = false # tell AR this is not a new record
    end

    true
  end
end
```

This should give back full use of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` again.

---

[gist](https://gist.github.com/1236566) w/tests

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas: Have you taken a look at association callbacks? Perhaps you can "intercept" accepts_nested_attributes_for at this level, using :before_add to check if it is already in the DB before creating a new record.

The other idea is to post-process instead. In an after_save/update you could look up all of the records with the name (that ought to be unique), and if there's more than one then merge them.

Comment: I've not looked at association callbacks, no.  I'll take a look.  I'll also look at the post-process suggestion.  One potential gotcha is that the overarching record (within which the attributes are nested) needs to be created with the Id of the nested record.  I guess that could also be fixed in post-processing, but it's not ideal.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to write a before_save function, but you say this:

> It uses accepts_nested_attributes_for to create the PurchaseOrder record.

So in the `SalesTransaction` process flow, why look it up at all?  You should just get the next one available... there shouldn't be a reason to search for something that didn't exist until NOW.

Comment: Not in the case of this field, no.  The foreign_id field for this record is not set in all cases.

Comment: Can you add actual names of the models you are dealing with? It will help everyone.  You have more then one place to create records, eh?

Comment: Actually upon further thinking, you are either creating a record or you aren't.  meaning, in any case, the nested record needs a name field.  Or are you saying this name field is optional in most cases, unless you are creating a nested record?

Comment: OK, I've added in the model names to provide better context, thanks for the suggestion.  The name (now 'purchase_order_number') is a mandatory field, which may or may not have an existing 'duplicate'.  If the purchase_order_number (e.g. PO #1234) already exists, I want to link the SalesTransaction to the existing PurchaseOrder.